# Instantiating a Class by passing an Enum (without values) as an argument

Tags: java, enums

I want to instantiate a Class that has an Instance variable of type `enum`. This `enum` has got no values which is strange. I have to pass this `enum` as an argument while creating an object of this class but I am not sure how to pass the `enum` without any values.

Class:

```
public class AddressStandardizationRequestParameter extends RequestParameter <AddressStandardizationRequestParameter.PARAMETERS, String> {
    public enum PARAMETERS { };

    public AddressStandardizationRequestParameter(PARAMETERS key, String value)   {
        super(key, value);
    }

}
```

I know if this enum had values I could say `PARAMETER.enumConstant` but in above case how would I do it?

Comment: The only option is to pass `null`.

Comment: Do you want the enum to be one with values, but you don't want to use a specific enum (allowing instances of your class to have different types)?  Or do you want it to actually be an empty enum?

Comment: @Mark. I passed null but in Cobertura report, it shows uncovered.

Comment: @Yousuf What is uncovered? The enum or the constructor? Either way, you shouldn't care because there are no enum instances, so you can't do anything with it (other than `null`).

Comment: @Pokechu. Actually this is some kind of legacy code and I am writing Junit test case for it. So, while creating an instance of it I face this issue and I am think it should be an empty enum.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like generated code, from a not very good generator as well.

Comment: @Mark, enum shows uncovered. You mean there is no way to do it.

Comment: @Yousuf No, there is no way to do it, because there is nothing to cover. There's no code associated with the empty enum that you could test. That it shows up as uncovered is probably a bug in Cobertura.

Comment: Coverage is a tool to improve software quality, it should not be a target in itself. There is no code in the enum, so why do you care about its coverage at all.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Unfortunately there are certain companies out there who enforce "quality standards" this way. (Which is rather ironic because the quoted code definitely wouldn't pass a proper review in the first place.)

Comment: @biziclop I know, and to be honest it can be useful to have a target if done for the right reasons. But it looks like some people confuse the intended benefit with bending over to make the target (which usually results in tests that don't actually check anything...).

Comment: @Everyone. I think based on what we have discussed make sense not to test such a code as it doesn't have anything to cover. Thank you so much all, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

enum type can not be instantiated by "new".

enum can only be used by the enum constant list and its methods.

Therefore an empty enum can't be passed as arg to a method.

Comment: `null` is always a valid value for an enum reference.

Comment: @Sahar. I am not instantiating an enum. I am just trying to pass an enum without any values or constants in the constructor. As others have mentioned that null is a valid value and this is the default for enum as well but if I pass null i get no code coverage.

Comment: @biziclop, Off course null is valid, but this is not what Yousuf asked.

Comment: @Yousuf, passing an enum as arg means it needs to be instantiated with a certain value. This can only happen if the enum has constants list.

Comment: @Sahar, You are correct but I think in my case there is no point of testing this code anymore  since it got no constants.